# worklight tracking

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I still no able  to successfully download/install an app thru IBM app center to see what a new app looks like on a mobile device.

2  simple questions :

1) If an app, let's call it myapp,  was download/install successfully thru IBM app center, then would myapp simply an independent new app on the device or myapp some how "embedded" in the  worklight app center app?

2) If I deployed myapp to a Samsung tablet thru other means, that is not thru IBM app center, then would worklight serve has the knowledge of myadd install in this particular Samsung device?

Comment: if your question is answered, please mark it.

Answer (score 0):

1. The application would be independent. You could, for example, uninstall it either through the Application Center mobile client, or via the usual procedure the device OS allows you to.
2. Assuming the applications has connectOnStartup=true, and you deployed the app to the Worklight Server, the answer would be Yes. (the Application Center is not a substitute to the Worklight Server, you must still deploy it there if you intent for your application to use features such as Worklight Adapters).

Comment: Okay...  then could I just deploy the adapter but not the "app" (I meant the wlapp file) to the Worklight server?  Assuming I don't care (I do care but just trying to have better understand how it works) for push, etc features provided by worklight server.

Comment: You will have to set your application's initOptions so that connectOnStartup = false. You will of course lose a lot of features, such as also not being able to disable an application, send notifications to applications, remotely update applications and more.

Comment: @Tara, if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.